# Django-tenants "Unable to create the django_migrations table"

Tags: python, django, django-tenants

An issue occurred where our production database was not getting migrated due to an error during migration. This error involved the usage of the package `django-tenants`, which is a fork of the `django-tenant-schemas` package.

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/backend/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/backend/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 89, in handle
    executor.run_migrations(tenants=tenants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/standard.py", line 14, in run_migrations
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): o1380729.ingest.sentry.io:443
    run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, schema_name, idx=idx, count=len(tenants))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/base.py", line 45, in run_migrations
    migration_recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 70, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (relation "django_migrations" already exists
)
```

What could cause this error?

Comment: Have you deleted any migrations or overwritten any of them?

Comment: No migrations were changed or deleted. I did this as a Q&A style question to help anyone in the future because this is a tough bug to figure out. If you scroll down you'll see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that several tenants *did* migrate before the error occurred tells you that the error is caused by a specific tenant. To find where the error is coming from we need to follow the traceback. On the second to last line we see:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/standard.py", line 14, in run_migrations 
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): o1380729.ingest.sentry.io:443 run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, schema_name, idx=idx, count=len(tenants)) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/base.py", line 45, in run_migrations migration_recorder.ensure_schema() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py"
```

So looking into the `django_tenants` source code near line 45 of `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_tenants/migration_executors/base.py` we see this code:

```
    connection = connections[options.get('database', get_tenant_database_alias())]
    connection.set_schema(schema_name, tenant_type=tenant_type)

    # ensure that django_migrations table is created in the schema before migrations run, otherwise the migration
    # table in the public schema gets picked and no migrations are applied
    migration_recorder = MigrationRecorder(connection)
    migration_recorder.ensure_schema() # line 45
```

Since the `schema_name` is passed to `connection.set_schema(schema_name, tenant_type=tenant_type)` we can go up one line and put a print statement to print the name of the schema being migrated. This print statement will show on the console during migrations and show the schema which has the issue. In our case, it was cause by duplicate schema names being allowed because of different capitalization in the schema names.

To change the schema names we went into the Django shell using `python manage.py shell`, imported the tenant model, called `instance = TenantModel.objects.get(schema_name="conflicting_name")` and set the schema to a different name using `instance.schema_name("new_name")` and called `instance.save()` on the instance.

This ran a migration and fixed the issue!